# Is it safe to delete stale Core Data records using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler?

Tags: ios, core-data, background

My co-workers are wary of using a background task to handle bulk-cleanup of stale data in our on-board database. It seems to me like the ideal place to do cleanup since it will not impact the user experience.

What is the best practice for bulk cleanup of Core Data? Is it safe to do it using a BG Task? i.e Is it safe to delete stale Core Data records using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler? if not, what is the recommended way?

Comment: Just to clarify, by *background task*, do you mean a task that runs in background thread, or one that runs when the app is in the background?

Comment: One spawned by beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler on aplicationWillResignActive which then runs while the app is in the background.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott,

I do database garbage collection in the background all of the time. It works very well. IOW, if you follow standard CD multi-threading patterns, it is safe. One note: `-applicationWillResignActive:` is called much more often than you might think. I recommend that you start your cleanup in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

Andrew